# Accessing a jar file inside vendor from packages/apps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, dalvik

I have 2 jar files residing inside `Linux/android/vendor/myjar/libs/frameworks` . I need to access this jar  from my application inside `Linux/android/packages/apps`

How should I specify the  `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` in the Android.mk of my application such that I can access these jar's from my application.

`(1) core.jar and (2) porting.jar` is the name of the jar files `Linux/android/vendor/myjar/libs/frameworks`. If someone can help me define the `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES`, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you  brief me , the folder in vendor/myjar is an `.jar` file or `.java` files from which `.jar` is generated. You can use `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES = myjars` in make file.

myjars is a folder name of `.java` class , if you are using `.jar` files directly you can include in your project by using `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` in the `Android.mk` of our application

Comment: `Linux/android/vendor/myjar/libs/frameworks` contains .jar files which I need to access. The .jar files are provided by third party.

Comment: Can you use these jar file directly in you app , by pasting it in ur apps or you must access from vendor .

Comment: When I place the jar file in the libs folder of my application and compile, I get the following error `vendor/abc/libs/frameworks: MODULE.TARGET.JAVA_LIBRARIES.core.jar already defined by packages/apps/SkeletonFindme` . ie; the compiler says that I cannot duplicate the jar's already present

Comment: then , what happens if it is not included in ur app. Whaat type of error it gives.

Comment: if jar is not included in app, the build works ok, but on runtime it says classnotfound exception while trying to access the class inside jar